# how to "do something" while the scrollview content is past certain point

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

How can I make a button disappear (basically just go transparent) while the uiimage in my uiscrollview is scrolled past a certain point (for example 100 on the y axis) and for it to appear again when it's scrolled back up again.

Put simply, I want the opacity of a button to go to 0 when the user scrolls down past a certain point and then for the opacity to return to normal when its scrolled back past the point.

I've searched everywhere for an answer but nothing seems to be relevent to me and it just doesn't work and it comes with many different warnings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Solved !!!

1) delegate,

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

2) set the  delegate

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

3) put this delegate method,

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >100){
        if((int)self.button.layer.opacity==1){
            self.button.layer.opacity = 0;
        }
    }else{
        if((int)self.button.layer.opacity==0){
            self.button.layer.opacity = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

4) don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` since you deal with button.layer

Comment: After the answer was edited it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!